# res.send() not working in node

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using promise and sending the response but with in the .then() function I can't send the response using res.send();

My code is

```js
        var express = require ('express'); //EXPRESS Package
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');// get body-parser
    var route = express.Router(); //define our app using express
    var multer = require('multer');
    var validator = require('validator');
    var userModel = require('../../model/user.model');
    var session = require('express-session');
    route.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    route.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
    // route.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }))

    route.put("/personal/:id", function (req, res) {

        data = {};
        data['personal_details'] = req.body;
       return userModel.update(req.params.id, data).then( function (result) {
            // console.lssog(result);
            res.send();
        }).catch( function ( err ){

          res.send(err).status(400);
        });
    });

    // route.put("/contact/:id", function (req, res) {

    //     userModel.update(req.params.id, "contact_details", req.body).then( function () {
            
    //         res.sendStatus(200)
    //     }).catch( function ( err ){

    //       res.send(err).status(400);
    //     });
    // });
    module.exports = route;
```

Users Model file is user.model.js which is shown below:

```js
var passwordHash = require('password-hash');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var Q = require('q');
var _ = require('lodash');
var randomstring = require('randomstring');
var db = mongo.db('mongodb://127.0.0.1/angulardemo');

db.bind('demotest');
// var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("12345", salt);
var model       = {};
model.login     = login;
model.create    = create;
model.update    = update;
model.destroy   = destroy;
model.edit      = edit; 

module.exports = model;

/**
 * Create new user
 * @param {request data} userData 
 */
function create (userData){
    
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    db.demotest.findOne({"email" : userData.email}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(err);

        if(user){

            deferred.reject('Email "' + userData.email + '" is already taken');
        }
        else{

            createUser();
        }
    });
    
    function createUser() {

        var user = _.omit(userData, ['password', 'c_password']);
        var hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate(userData.password);
        user.password = hashedPassword;
        user.api_token = randomstring.generate(50);
        user.registration_code = randomstring.generate(10);
        user.is_active = 1;
        user.is_verified = 1;
        db.demotest.insert(user, function (err, doc) {

            if (err) deferred.reject(err);

            deferred.resolve();
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;

}

/**
 * Login user
 * @param {user request data} data 
 */
function login(data) {
    
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    db.demotest.findOne({"email" : data.email}, function (err, user) {

        if (err) deferred.reject(err);

        if(!user) deferred.reject("User not found");
        if(user && passwordHash.verify(data.password, user.password)){

            deferred.resolve(user);
        }
        else{

            deferred.reject("Invalid Credential");
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
/**
 * Update User
 * @param {user id} id 
 * @param {user data} data 
 */
function update(id, data){
    
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    // validation
    db.demotest.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(err);

        if (user.id !== id) {
            // username has changed so check if the new username is already taken
            db.demotest.findOne(
                { _id: id },
                function (err, user) {
                    if (err) deferred.reject(err);

                    if (user) {
                        // username already exists
                        deferred.reject('User "' + user.username + '" is already taken')
                    } else {
                        updateUser();
                    }
                });
        } else {
            updateUser();
        }
    });

    function updateUser() {

        db.demotest.update(
            { _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(id) },
            { $set: data },
            function (err, doc) {
                if (err) deferred.reject(err);
                deferred.reject("err");
            });
    }

    return deferred.promise;





    // var deferred = Q.defer();
    // db.demotest.update({_id : mongo.helper.toObjectID(id)}, {$set: data}, function (err, result) {
    //     console.log(result);
    //     if (err) deferred.reject(err);

    //     deferred.resolve("OLLLL");

    // });

    // return deferred.promise;
}

function destroy() {

}

function edit() {
    
}





// var insertTestDoc = function (db, callback) {
//     //console.log("one"); return ;
//     var collection = db.collection('demotest');

//     collection.insertOne({"title" : "demotest", "description" : "Lorem Ipsum Sit Emet.", "password" : hash}, function ( err, db ){
//         assert.equal(err, null);
//         callback();
//     });

// }
// var login = function (db, callback) {

//     var collection = db.collection('demotest')

//     var cursor = collection.findOne({"title" : "demotest"});
//     console.log(cursor);
// //     cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
// //       assert.equal(err, null);
// //       if (doc != null) {
// //          console.log(doc);
// //       } else {
// //          callback();
// //       }
// //    });
// }
// MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/angulardemo', function ( err, db ){

//     assert.equal( null, err );
//     console.log("Connected to the server correctly");
//     login(db, function () {
//         db.close();
//     });
//     // insertTestDoc(db, function () {
//     //     db.close();
//     // });

// });
```

Please assist thanks

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: No response getting. It's pending.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities based on what you've shown, one of which depends on the version of mongoose you're using. Actually, the use of mongoose is an assumption on my part, since you never mention it...

The more likely one is that you're never actually connecting to the database.  In your code, somewhere, there needs to be a call to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` that fires on app startup (or at least before the request hangs that you're seeing).

If you are in fact doing that and just didn't share it, then the next most likely thing is that you're using a version of mongoose before 4.0, in which queries (e.g. `.update()`) didn't follow the Promise api, and you had call `exec()` like:

```
myModel.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, data).exec().then(...);
```

If I'm wrong in my assumption about mongoose, or if both my suggestions are wrong please update your question with the relevant info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am using mongoskin